# Delete all occurrences of a pattern apart from the first one

Tags: sed

I am trying to clean up the output from a code generator. Unfortunately it generates multiple imports:

```
import Foo
...
import Foo
```

Luckily generated text is relatively static, though it gets regenerated often, thus what I'm hoping is that there is an easy way to remove this.

I've worked out that if they were on the same line I could: `sed 's/import Foo//2g'`

However I don't know sufficient sed to make it consider just all lines.

A hacky solution would be to run multiple seds...

```
sed 's/\n/<string I know doesn't appear>/g'
sed 's/import Foo//2g'
sed 's/<string I know doesn't appear>/\n'
```

But that doesn't feel right to do. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The better approach would be to fix the problem at the source: can you fix the code generator?

Comment: Is that always `import Foo`, or other `import ...` s , too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '/^import Foo$/{x;/^$/!d;g;}'
```

How it works:  On each line matching the pattern

- `x`: swap the line with the hold space
- `/^$/!d`: if what's just been fetched from hold space isn't empty, ie. because a previous match was stored there, delete the pattern and advance to the next line
- `g`: otherwise (ie. the first time through) copy the saved line back.  It will be printed by default

Answer (score 4):

With the GNU implementation of `sed` (which you're probably using as you're using that `2g` GNUism alread), you could do:

```
sed '0,/import Foo/!{//d}' < file
```

Which would delete all lines containing `import Foo` except for the first one. Replace the pattern with `/^import Foo$/` if you want to only  delete lines that *are exactly* `import Foo`.

You could also use `awk` here:

```
awk '!/import Foo/ || !n++' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `sed` version allows for it, try

```
sed -z 's/import Foo//2g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, portable, etc. and ust use awk:

```
$ cat file
import Foo
import Bar
import More
import Foo
import Stuff
import Bar

$ awk '!seen[$0]++' file
import Foo
import Bar
import More
import Stuff
```

or if it's just the lines that start with `import` you want to make unique and you have other lines in the input you don't want touched:

```
$ cat file
import Foo
int 3;
import Bar
char 7;
import More
int 3;
import Foo
char 7;
import Stuff
whatever
import Bar
whatever

$ awk '!(/^import/ && seen[$0]++)' file
import Foo
int 3;
import Bar
char 7;
import More
int 3;
char 7;
import Stuff
whatever
whatever
```

Comment: Be careful, that ends up deleting all duplicate lines (e.g. each '}' ending a function in C...)

Comment: @vonbrand did you read the whole answer including the 2nd script and the sentence above it?